# Java function overload ambiguity with custom class

Tags: java, overloading

I have two function calls: one that takes a string as a param and another that takes an Object. When I do this:

```
foo(Object a){...}
foo(String s){...}
```

and then call:

```
foo(null);
```

it works fine.

---

However if I do this:

```
foo(CustomClass a){...}
foo(String s){...}
```

and then call:

```
foo(null);
```

Eclipse tells me that it is ambiguous. So two questions:

1. Why isn't the first case ambiguous?
2. How do I fix?

Answer (score 7):

> Why isn't the first case ambiguous?

That's because `String` is a subtype of `Object`, and compiler chooses the most specific one. And hence method with `String` parameter is chosen.

> How do I fix?

Well, In the 2nd case, since the two parameter types are not in the same inheritance hierarchy, you will get ambiguity. You can't avoid it. Because, `null` is equally eligible to be assigned to both the `types`. There is no one specific type for the compiler to chose between.

You can avoid the `ambiguity error` by explicitly casting `null` to the required type.

So, the below invocations will work fine: -

```
foo((String)null);   
foo((CustomClass)null);
```

Comment: The compiler cannot choose, but if is known which method is to be  invoked null can be casted to the type desired type in order to infer the method.

Comment: @pabrantes. Why would there be casting at all? Isn't `null` an exact match for `String` and `CustomClass` both?

Comment: you are correct on what you've said, but since the return type isn't part of the method's signature, foo(String) and foo(CustomClass) may return different types, if you know which return type you're looking for, an explicit cast would fix the problem. This is a corner case though (and most of the times a bad interface design) but it happens

Comment: INteresting thread about it: http://www.coderanch.com/t/382683/java/java/Casting-null-object

Comment: @pabrantes.. Actually now I understood, what you were trying to say. Edited the answer accordingly. Thanks :)